# How to find out which version of Rails includes a fix for a specific issue?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, release-management

How do I find out which version of Rails includes this issue?

https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/29551

The release notes don't give details.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/5_0_release_notes.html#test-runner

Answer (score 0):

One way of finding out which release version would include the specific commit, is by first `clicking on the commit to view the changes` that took place there. Github nicely lays out the list of changes on a single page, for example for your case :

https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/ab600b1a9268dd5fb00ecccc97f258bcf1c0119d

[image]

Check the tags(marked with a red box in the image) attached to the commit. That should tell you which version the change is available in.

Comment: Yeah but that tag is not definitive. I ran `bundle update` with `gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.2'` and it fixed my problem, and I do not have 5.2. So that tag seems erroneous. It was included somewhere before 5.0.6.